# how to install a specific version of grpcurl?

Tags: go, grpcurl

I tried to use

```
go get github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl@2108c8f
go install github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/cmd/grpcurl
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

to install grpcurl on my ubuntu box, but after that when I do grpcurl --version I still got

> grpcurl dev build

I expect to see

```
grpcurl 1.16.0
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Without using Go, download the executable:

```
wget https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/download/v1.7.0/grpcurl_1.7.0_linux_x86_64.tar.gz

tar -xvf grpcurl_1.7.0_linux_x86_64.tar.gz

chmod +x grpcurl

./grpcurl -help
```

More versions and binaries available from the [grpcurl releases](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases) page.